# Problems with foreign key ids'

Tags: php

I'm trying to delete images from database and folder aswell. The problem is, I don't know how to get the id of the image instead of the cardid.
My database looks like this:

card

```
id - name - etc.
```

cardimages

```
id - image - cardid (foreign key)
```

Here's my code:

```
    if (!empty($_POST['delete'])) {
      $name = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, image FROM cardimages WHERE cardid= ?");
      $name->bind_param('i', $_POST['id']);
      $name->execute();
      $res = $name->get_result();
      $row = $res->fetch_assoc();
      $name1 = $row['image'];

      if ($stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM cardimages WHERE id = ?")) {
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $row['id']);
        unlink($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/$name1");
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
      }
    }
```

The problem is with this line:

```
 $stmt->bind_param('i', $row['id']);
```

I don't know how to get the id of the image here.

Comment: I'm a little confused here, so for the cardimages table referenced here: `$name = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, image FROM cardimages WHERE cardid= ?");`, is that a separate table from card and image, or are you trying to select from both of those tables?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. 'cardimages' is the name of the image table, not 'image'. Edited it.

Comment: So, does `$row['id']` not return the id of the cardimages row?

Comment: No, and I don't really understand why.

Comment: Try running this same sql query directly to see if you get a result: `SELECT id, image FROM cardimages WHERE cardid= ?` (replace ? with the cardid you want to select). Right now I see a few different possibilities. One is the data isn't in the database anymore, another is the $_POST data isn't being passed on correctly, so it either skips the entire block or the id isn't being passed on. There could also be something misspelled somewhere causing the issue, but let's rule out the first 2 options first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an extension of my comments from above.

If you are able to successfully run the query `SELECT id, image FROM cardimages WHERE cardid= ?` directly and it returns a result, try the following in your code. In `$name->bind_param('i', $_POST['id']);` change `$_POST['id']` with a variable that is hard coded to be an Id you know to be in the database, for example:

```
$cardid = 123; //Replace 123 with an Id you know to be in the database.
$name->bind_param('i', $cardid); //bind_param requires a variable, which is why you need to create a variable with the hard coded id.
```

Next, try running the code again. If it successfully returns a value this time, then your `$_POST['id']` is not selecting the appropriate id, so check your form where you are submitting the id. Common issues on the form are not specifying `method="POST"` (The default form method is "GET", so if "POST" is not specified, your code will not work), or having the field where the ID is supposed to be either having the wrong name, maybe something like `name="Id"` (names are case sensitive) or not having the id populate in the input's value field.

If, however, your code does not return a value after adding the hard coded id, then your connection to the database is not working. Check to make sure you have the correct values when creating a new mysqli connection. You need to ensure that the following information is correct and in the following order `new mysqli("HOST","USERNAME","PASSWORD","DATABASE");` Common issues here is the host is incorrect, sometimes the host is not `localhost` but `127.0.0.1`, or vice versa, or that the user credentials are wrong or the user does not have access to the database selected. Sometimes, people will skip the password field if the user does not have a password, make sure that if that is the case, still fill in the password field with `""` instead of skipping it.